# woocommerce simple-registration template override not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have this woocommerce-simple-registration plugin in my wordpress and also i have my child theme. I want to override the plugin with my child theme in registration page/form.

These are the directories;

plugin
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-simple-registration/templates/registration-form-php

child theme
*i did try put the override here but it doesn't work
wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/templates/woocommerce-simple-registration/registration-form-php

*the other one is this directory but still not working
wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/woocommerce/woocommerce-simple-registration/registration-form-php

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try creating a new plugin which over-rides the previous
   plugin files without disturbing updates
2. For Child Theme this should work `wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/woocommerce-simple-registration/templates/registration-form-php`